# Twitter bootstrap 3 navbar navbar-right outside navbar-collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 I can have something like:
http://jsfiddle.net/aQwUZ/3/

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">

                <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="brand">BRAND</a>
                <ul class="nav  pull-right">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Fixed Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#">L2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

A twitter bootstrap navbar, where in mobile responsive view, "Fixed Link" stay visible in header.

Now, in bootstrap 3, after upgrade my code, I can only have:
http://jsfiddle.net/EC3Ly/4/

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Fixed Link</a>
                          </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                         <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#">L2</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
</nav>
```

in mobile responsive view, I get 2 lines... 
I tried to wrap in a "navbar-header" node http://jsfiddle.net/EC3Ly/5/ or in the first "navbar-header" without success.

What did I miss?

Thanks,

Alexandre

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two lines in the mobile navbar are caused by the clearfix of the navbar-header:

```
.navbar-header {
  .clearfix();

  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

You could use media queries and css to undo this clearfix (and add a new before the collapsed dropdown)

```
.navbar-right {float: right !important;}

@media(max-width:767px)
{
    .navbar-right {margin-right:20px;}
    .navbar-header:after 
    {
    clear: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right > li { float: left; }

    .navbar-collapse:before {clear:both;}

    .navbar-collapse {overflow-y: hidden;}
    .navbar-collapse.in {overflow-y: visible;}
    .navbar{border-color: #101010; border-width: 0 0 1px;}
    .navbar-collapse.in > ul {border-color: #101010; border-top:1px double;}
}

}
```

demo: http://bootply.com/82366

The media queries also add a float right for the navbar-right on smaller screens. To take this code in production, you maybe will fix the borders and possible the navbar css transisions too.

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same problem with BS3, and the only way I found to resolve it was to use a combination of `pull-left` and `pull-right`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Fixed Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L2</a></li>
      </ul>                    
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Working demo: http://bootply.com/78856

Comment: I also try with pull-left and pull-right, but this solution break some behavior in mobile view: _ "Fixed Link" can't have a right margin and when this node is dropdown node, it turns very bad.

Comment: @heralight I had to manually override the bootstrap dropdown styles for `.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu` and `.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a`

Comment: If you have multiple fixed links they stack on top of one another when collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the point at which the `navbar` collapses. By default, Bootstrap collapses at 768px. If you increase this, your `navbar` will collapse sooner and your problem will disappear.

The best way to do this is to customize your bootstrap file and change the `@grid-float-breakpoint` to 850px (or whatever size you need). You can easily customize bootstrap 3 from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=9720390

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way. Just right after the brand add two new lines with the same class and an additional class.

```
        <!-- Branding Image -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
        <!-- Fake branding to avoid breaking up navbar -->
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-fake">Item 1</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-fake">Item 2</a>
```

And add this to your css file:

```
a.navbar-brand-fake {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 21px;
    margin-left: 2px !important;
}
```

Home, Item 1 and Item 2 remain in the navbar when resizing and the navbar won't break.