# keeping a navbar ul horizontal on small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap navbar that has 2 ul's in it.

the first UL hides into the collapse menu on small screens.

the second UL is still visible.

the problem i've run into, is that second UL always displays vertically.  i can't seem to override it to display horizontally.  i keep inspecting the css , but nothing i've found seems to control that.

http://www.bootply.com/render/121627

( some of the css is borrowed from // [Twitter bootstrap 3 navbar navbar-right outside navbar-collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610249/twitter-bootstrap-3-navbar-navbar-right-outside-navbar-collapse) )

To clarify:

this is what I see on <760px wide screens:

```
 [ brand ]     -item1      [---]
               -item2
```

this is what i want to see:

```
 [ brand ] -item1 -item2  [---]
```

Comment: Hmm, not 100% sure what you mean by display horizontally, unfortunately. Can you specify exactly what kind of behaviour you're aiming for?

Comment: ah, i got it!  `.navbar-right > ul > li { float:left; }`  I updated the Bootply.

Comment: Ah, I see! That's what you meant, I wasn't sure. Well, glad you were able to work it out on your own.

Answer (score 2):

the solution was to target the ul>li on the navbar.

```
.navbar-right > ul > li { float:left; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me in a similar situation:

```
.navbar-right {
    float: right;
}

.navbar-right > li {
    float: left
}

.navbar-right > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4:

```
.navbar-nav { flex-direction:row !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4, add `flex-row` to the `ul` element of the navigation bar.(the `ul` element which contains `li` elements.